# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'PropsAllowlists')

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

Used navigation, reanimated and drawer versions:

```
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.6.1",
```

This error is thrown while I toggle the drawer and this error can be minimized and then I continue the further process. But I want to know the permanent resolution.[image]

[Github iOS Issue](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/11729)

[image: Another error on iOS]

Comment: Check the compatibility of used modules by installing them again with @latest at the end.

for example: npm install @react-navigation/drawer@latest and so on

Comment: If it's not the compatibility of modules problem, we can do much without the actual code of the drawer

Comment: @wolfie00 I am already on the latest libs modules but still it throws this error at random times even after re-installing the app. Now, I can predict it's related to reanimated not Drawer.

Answer (score 0):

This fixes this issue. When the emulator is overloaded with cache, your error occurs.

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean --force && npm install && watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-map-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-cache
```

After that, run:

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

Comment: This error is also thrown when I debug the app using chrome, tried your code but still same.